# How to paginate metaobjects in Shopify?

Tags: pagination, shopify, liquid

I'm using metaobjects in combination with metafields to render some specific information in the product page in a Shopify template.

The problem I'm currently facing is that getting metaobjects through liquid code only returns 50 results. However, I would like to paginate those results. Right now I have:

```
....
{%- capture hex_color -%}
{% assign current_fabric_colors = shop.metaobjects.fabric_colors %}
{% for color in current_fabric_colors.values %}
   {% if color.name == handle[1] %}
       color.name
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{%- endcapture -%}
....
```

The problem is that "shop.metaobjects.fabric_colors.values" only returns 50 values, and Liquid documentation is very poor about metaobjects: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/metaobject#metaobject_definition-loop-over-entries-of-a-metaobject-definition

PD: I have 59 metaobject entries in fabric_colors and every single one of them is "Active".

I have tried to replicate the following without being successful (it throws an error when appending the method call .offset and .limit as if liquid doesn't accept it): https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/using-metaobjects-cannot-access-more-than-50-entries-in-theme/td-p/1963918

As metaobjects is a recent feature from Shopify, I'm afraid this has not been taken into consideration, at least to be solved through Liquid and not the Storefront API (which should be callable through Liquid).

PD: I'm not too experienced in Shopify's Liquid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @community Well, I think the following sentence "The problem I'm currently facing is that getting metaobjects through liquid code only returns 50 results. However, I would like to paginate those results." is clear enough. Do you need me to reformulate this into a question mark sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would think about it and determine if maybe you're not better off having ONE object, with 59 entries. As an example, a JSON field can easily hold 59 values. Also, a Metaobject is meant to hold many smaller items right? So instead of 59 Metaobjects, you could have one, and it then contains many smaller objects, like Metafields.

You choose how to re-arrange the deck chairs, and it is up to you. Shopify has always limited naked queries to 50 items, so as not to burden the system. Paginating these resources though seems a bit much. Colors and Hex Codes are ideal as a JSON Key:Value object. Assigned once to the store and you can re-use them anywhere with nothing but a simple snippet you render.

Comment: That makes sense @david-lazar, thanks for your reply. I interpreted metaobjects as the key value itself being the namespace the whole JSON. If not, namespace should be then more generic (currently I have it as "Fabric Colors"), maybe it should be "attributes" and inside this namespace add a single metaobject called "fabric_colors" that hold a JSON? It seems weird to me that Shopify allows to add more than 50 entries if no more than 50 can be retrieved through Liquid.

Comment: You are correct. Namespace is best something that makes sense. Like a namespace of fabric, perhaps holding a key of colors, saving a value of some JSON object. As for limits, it is not actually weird. While you could theoretically assign hundreds to something, you'd know, and write appropriate paging code. All in all, it works fine, and you just have to get used to how it works, rather than why certain choices were made. 

That being said, I used to hack the API to ensure I got back 250 per request instead of 50. Had to back then!